# Image display differences between iOS 4.3.3 and iOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, safari

I have the following image source which I am trying to display in UIWebView

```
<img src="http://img1" style="padding-top:23px; padding-right:40px; position: fixed; left:-100px; " width=280px; height=2px;>
```

In iOS 4.3.3 it displays the image correctly, though in 5.0.1 it is not displayed at all.
Also happens in Safari.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Need a bit more context, is it in a div, does the parent div have any styling options? are you using Jquery Mobile or Sencha Touch? We are having the opposite problem atm. As in our images are not showing in ios 4.3 UIWebView but is in Safari and is showing in IOS 5.0.1.